# How to set String value in Mule variables

Tags: xpath, mule

I want to store an expression in flow variable and want to retrieve it as same that I stored....
For example :-

```
<set-variable doc:name="Variable" value="#[xpath('//v1:insertDataRequest/v1:Id').text]" variableName="cacheKey"/>
```

Here in the flow variable called **cacheKey** I want to store the expression `#[xpath('//v1:insertDataRequest/v1:Id').text]` as a String so that if I want to retrieve it such as following

`<logger message="#[flowVars['cacheKey']" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>`

It should retrieve me the value of `#[flowVars['cacheKey']` as `#[xpath('//v1:insertDataRequest/v1:Id').text]` as a String

But in my case whenever I am trying to store

```
 <set-variable doc:name="Variable" value="#[xpath('//v1:insertDataRequest/v1:Id').text]" variableName="cacheKey"/>
```

It is extracting the **xpath** value with **current message payload** and I am getting the extracted value of xpath from payload instead of getting `#[xpath('//v1:insertDataRequest/v1:Id').text]`

So, my question is how can I store the value  `#[xpath('//v1:insertDataRequest/v1:Id').text]` as a String in flowVars so that I get exactly  `#[xpath('//v1:insertDataRequest/v1:Id').text]` as flowVars value and not **extracted value** of **xpath**
Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
 <set-variable doc:name="Variable" value="#['#[xpath('//v1:insertDataRequest/v1:Id').text]']" variableName="cacheKey"/>
```

EDIT:

Apostrophes should be escaped

```
<set-variable doc:name="Variable" value="#['#[xpath(\'//v1:insertDataRequest/v1:Id\').text]']" variableName="cacheKey"/>
```

Comment: I tried your expression and when I tried to retrieve the value using logger :- `<logger message="Value :- #[flowVars['cacheKey']]" level="INFO"/>` .. I am getting only the following :- `Value :- #[xpath(` ... Strange .. I am not getting the full expression

Comment: @AnirbanSenChowdhary Sorry, the inner apostrophes should be escaped. Edited the answer with the correrct code.

Comment: I come late to the discussion, I read badly at the first time, but given that there is no 'eval' in MVEL, how do you expect to execute that expression inside the Mule MVEL context?

Comment: @VíctorRomero The intention is not to evaluate the expression, but store its string representation in the variable

Comment: Oh it was all about that! They only thing actually required to do so is to separate the # from the [, otherwise escaping like mentioned before is fine.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as an eval that reuses the current context in MVEL, and therefor even if you get to store the value as per ~nuno (or just separating somehow the # from the [, perhaps with string appenders) you won't be able to execute it.

I can't see the big picture of your problem, but with what I can guess I would use rather than this a [property placeholder](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Configuring+Properties#ConfiguringProperties-PropertyPlaceholders) with the expressions you need to be able to customise.

For the part of the questions, where you point that you don't wan't to loose the payload, just use an [enritcher](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Message+Enricher), it's designed exactly for that and anyone reading it will quickly understand what you were trying to do.

Comment: Hi, if I use the above expression than I will be getting the extracted value in flowVars as the **xpath** here is executing with the current payload which is a SOAP request ... So I will be getting extracted value instead of getting `#[xpath('//v1:insertDataRequest/v1:Id').text]`... But here I need `#[xpath('//v1:insertDataRequest/v1:Id').text]` in flowVars and not the extracted value ... Please suggest how to achieve that

Comment: Oh! I completely misreaded the question. Let me update the answer.

Comment: Thanks Victor .. Yes I can use a placeholder as you said .. but my intention is to store the expression itself as I need to pass the expression in a interceptor java class where I am evaluating the xpath in Java code and fetching the flowvars there in Java code... Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Sorry about the misreading. That sounds complex, make sure you really need to do something like that: component bindings, enritchers, component annotations and other might make a simpler approach.

Comment: Romero :- Sure Victor .. I will keep your suggestion in mind .. Thanks for your support :)

Answer (score 0):

So finally as Nuno suggested, the working solution is :-

```
<set-variable doc:name="Variable" value="#['#[xpath(\'//v1:insertDataRequest/v1:Id\').text]']" variableName="cacheKey"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can replace set-variable tag by:

```
<expression-component>
    flowVars.cacheKey = "#[xpath('//v1:insertDataRequest/v1:Id').text]";
</expression-component>
```

Comment: This is an overkill, set-variable is faster and self-explained

Comment: I tried using set-variable but it doesn't work. In this case, I think the expression-component meets the requirement but I will be alert to the thread if there are another way to do that.

Comment: Yes This way also works ... but as Victor said set variable will be faster and the expression in the set variable shown by Nuno is also working .. so I choose that as an answer .. But this is also working and I find it a great alternative way of doing this ... +1 for your effort and thank you so much for your support :).. I will mark this solution as an alternative approach in my code